# What is the name of the element that github copilot uses to highlighting text?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, github-copilot

I would like to make a control similar to the used by github copilot. I mean highlighting the proposed text. Live share extension uses a very similar approach. What is the name of this control?

Control in live preview extension:

[image: control in live preview extension]

Control in copilot extension:

[image: control in copilot extension]

I guess it could be TextEditorDecorationType? However, I do not know how to style it so that the author is absolutely positioned :/

Answer (score 1):

You can create a similar experience using **Text Editor Decorators**. These decorators allow you to use custom style patterns for any text in a document (including foreground and background colors).

The text highlighting examples that you have visualized above, are simply adding a a background color to a span of text that has been selected by a user, or suggested by an extension.

*As an example*: if you wanted to add custom highlighting for `console.log`:

[image]

Then you could use the following:

```js
import * as vscode from 'vscode'

const decorationType = vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType({
  backgroundColor: 'green',
  border: '2px solid white',
})

export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {
  vscode.workspace.onWillSaveTextDocument(event => {
    const openEditor = vscode.window.visibleTextEditors.filter(
      editor => editor.document.uri === event.document.uri
    )[0]
    decorate(openEditor)
  })
}

function decorate(editor: vscode.TextEditor) {
  let sourceCode = editor.document.getText()
  let regex = /(console\.log)/

  let decorationsArray: vscode.DecorationOptions[] = []

  const sourceCodeArr = sourceCode.split('\n')

  for (let line = 0; line < sourceCodeArr.length; line++) {
    let match = sourceCodeArr[line].match(regex)

    if (match !== null && match.index !== undefined) {
      let range = new vscode.Range(
        new vscode.Position(line, match.index),
        new vscode.Position(line, match.index + match[1].length)
      )

      let decoration = { range }

      decorationsArray.push(decoration)
    }
  }

  editor.setDecorations(decorationType, decorationsArray)
}
```

[Reference Link](https://vscode.rocks/decorations/)